# Saving multiple values with web_reg_save_param

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

I need some help with web_reg_save_param.

I have a request being called 10 times after each other, with ten times another response. I would like to make a FOR loop where I save a part of the response with web_reg_save_param. In the 11th request I have to do a POST call with all the ten responses after each other.

How to approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Amit

Answer (score 0):

This is a programming question involving a loop, the construction of a set of dynamic parameter names within the loop.   What have you tried?

```
[PCODE]

Loop Definition (foo)
{

construct variable name (yada_index) which contains an index from loop variable (foo)

Define correlation conditions, saving output to (yada_index)

GET URL

}


POST URL
  &var1=(yada)_1
  &var2=(yada)_2
  &va3r=(yada)_3
  ...
  &var10=(yada)_10
  &Other_vars

[/PCODE]
```

}